# Setting up another exhange 2010 server to be shipped overseas

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I've been a network admin for the past 8 years. But in most of my roles there has always been an exchange guy to handle the real ugly things. This has left me in an terrible position.
At one of my client sites i have installed a new server 2008 R2 64 bit machine. Set up domain, configured exchange, BES, backup exec, symantec. and another file server.
I have 2 more servers here that are to be configured and shipped to columbia. I have them built updated and now the hard part.
How can i install exchange onto this new server that is to be shipped over seas. Ive never really worked with multiple exchange servers (ones that are in other locations). 
Am I even able to set this up if i dont know what my pipe between us is going to be, or that the domain over there isnt established yet?
Its a newb question but im pretty intuitive.

Thanks so much for the tips.

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

I would insist on servers with remote-KVM capability -- like the HP iLO or Sun's eLOM or Dell's DRAC.  That way you can toggle the power remotely and interact with the system console during boot, eliminating the need to physically touch the computer unless there's something wrong with the hardware.

If you can, simulate the networking topology by creating a subnet that matches where the exchange server will live once it arrives overseas.  Then install and configure the software.  This sets up the AD and Exchange with the correct IP addresses, and should help you figure out some of the routing and remote-access issues when the system is across the hall instead of around the world.

I would try to do the installation as much as possible over Remote Desktop, or if necessary the remote-KVM.  That way you are getting used to managing the server without being physically present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Ther servers i have are HP and they do all have the iLO but i have never used it before. Im certain i understand the concept, and it sounds very useful for remote troubleshooting. SO basically maybe set the remote exchange server up in house on the same subnet that i will be using over there. Install exchange and when shiped make sure i use the same subnet at the new location. 
Can you think of any other complications that might occur moving it to south america?

And again thank for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I would say get it setup as much as you can with the easy stuff like updates and light config. Install logmein free on it, and send it out. Once the thing is connected and ready to communicate over a VPN of some sort, start the exchange install.